# event listener doesn't trigger when data changes firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As i told you in question when some data changes in firebase realtime databese nothing heppens on datachange() method.

I tried every eventlistener child,value and single but none of them worked.Please help me with that problem i am trying to solve it about 5 hours.

```
 public void StatusTextCheck(){

    typing_status.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Event listener triggered.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TypingStatus type = dataSnapshot.getValue(TypingStatus.class);


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

> Here is the reference define:
>
> ```
>      private DatabaseReference user_dbref, 
>      message_dbref,typing_status_dbref,typing_status;
>
>     user_dbref = database.getReference("Users");
>     message_dbref = database.getReference("Message");
>     typing_status = database.getReference("Typing_Status");
> ```

---

@PradyumanDixit

[image: Here is the structure of my database:]

Comment: can you share to us your database structure and also how you defined your reference typing_status ?

Comment: @GastonSailén i edited.

Comment: Add your database structure, and respond with @PradyumanDixit

Comment: @PradyumanDixit edited

Comment: Is your `database` variable properly defined? Also, you're referring to `onChildChanged()` method not being called when you change the child of `Typing_status` node in your Firebase Database, right?

Comment: First things first: don't ignore errors. At a minimum implement `onCancelled` as: `@Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
throw databaseError.toException();
        }` That way you know if your listener gets rejected by your security rules.

Comment: If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to can create a complete and functional [Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).